# Show Asterisk Icon for md-input having long labels

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

As stated in the docs, md-input do add an asterisk to the label if its a required type. But in case of input container, having width-constrained(e.g. restricting the width) and having long labels, the label is being truncated and the asterisk isnt being visible. So from a UX view point, its not getting intuitive that the field of the form is a required one, unless interacting with it.

Below I have created a small codepen to illustrate the point. Check both input fields are required, having different titles.

Code pen - [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQWEzd)

Ideally I would have wanted is trim the long text and also make the asterisk visible.

Any help/ suggestions is being appreciated :)

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.project = {
      description: 'Nuclear Missile Defense System',
      rate: 500
    };
  });
```

```css
.md-block {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="column" ng-cloak="" class="inputdemoErrors" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content>
    <form>
      <md-input-container class="md-block"> <label>LongTitleLongTitleLongTitleLongTitleLongTitleLongTitleLongTitle</label>
        <input ng-model="vm.job.title" ng-required="true">
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container class="md-block">
        <label>ShortTitle</label>
        <input ng-model="vm.job.title" ng-required="true">
      </md-input-container>
    </form>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you try to do ?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xrOpXx

```
.md-required {
  padding-right: 10px !important; //padding very important, else asterisk is hidden (overflow)
  width: auto !important; //width must be auto, by default it takes 100% so the asterisk is at right of the input
}

.md-required:after {
  color: red !important;
  width: 100%; // asterisk container has same width that label
  position: absolute; //position absolute and left 0 to be at same position than label
  left: 0;
  text-align: right; // with that, asterisk is at right
}
```